# Docker - Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have requested an impossible situation

Tags: node.js, docker, npm, apt, apt-get

I'm trying to start a Docker container. Here's the Dockerfile

```
FROM node:13.12.0-alpine as builder

WORKDIR '/app'
COPY package.json .
RUN npm install
COPY . .
RUN npm run build

FROM nginx

##
ARG NODE_VERSION=14
RUN curl -fsSL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_${NODE_VERSION}.x | bash - \
  && apt-get update \
  && apt-get autoremove \
  && apt-get install -y nodejs

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y npm
##

COPY --from=builder /app/build /usr/share/nginx/html
```

At first, I didn't have the content inside of the `##`. I added it there due to an error I was having when I was trying to run `npm run test` -> `docker-entrypoint.sh: 38: exec: npm: not found`. Since I added those to fix this problem, I'm having something else:

```
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 npm : Depends: nodejs (>= 6.11~) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-abbrev (>= 1.1.1~) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-ansi-regex (>= 3.0~) but it is not going to be installed
       ...

E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
The command '/bin/sh -c apt-get update && apt-get install -y npm' returned a non-zero code: 100
```

I tried to build the docker file with `docker build -t username/project_name --build-arg NODE_VERSION=15 .`

Comment: What is in the `docker-entrypoint.sh` script, and how is it being invoked?  Do you need to repeat your unit tests at startup time?  If your final application needs Node, would it be easier to start `FROM node` and either install Nginx or a Node-based HTTP server package?

Comment: Following a course so not really sure what I'm doing here. 1st day! There's no `docker-entrypoint.sh` file in the project.